# net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED en Apache, Angular, Node API Rest

Tags: nodejs, angular, ubuntu, apache, localhost

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto desarrollado en Angular con conexión a una API Rest hecha en Node, Express y Typescript.

He desplegado la App en un servidor Apache 2.4.29 en una instancia (máquina virtual) de EC2 (Ubuntu Server), pero este no se conecta a la API con dirección `localhost:4200` que se esta ejecutando en la misma instancia:

[image: Imagen 1]

Pensé que era la API que tenía algún problema pero está funcionando bien:

[image: Imagen 2]

Ya he leído la documentación de Apache, le eché un ojo al archivo de configuración y no se la verdad que puede estar pasando

Agradezco al que me pueda dar siquiera una pista de como solucionar este detalle y así evitar usar Nginx como segunda opción.

Comment: Que es lo que quieres hacer con apache?

Comment: crear un servidor para un proyecto que estoy desarrollando en angular.

Comment: Antes de subirlo a apache tuviste que hacer algo como `ng build ....`, y obtienes tu html e index en la carpeta build. Esos archivos son los que se suben, lo hiciste así?

Comment: Por supuesto, luego pasé a copiarlo en la ruta /var/www/html y funciona, el detalle es, como lo muestra la imagen, no se está conectando a la API que tengo en ese mismo servidor, ya miré el firewall y todo funciona bien.

Comment: Puedes poner como inicias tu api y en que puerto se esta ejecutando. La pregunta que te hice es por que veo en tu imagen que estas tratando de usar el puerto `4200` que normalmente lo usa angular cuando ejecutas `ng serve`.

Comment: Revisa si la API tiene configurada las CORS para acepte peticiones